# Android hide keyboard but a cursor stays on screen

Tags: android, cursor, indicator

Good morning!

On an app that I'm working on, I hide the soft keyboard and have a dark overlay appear on screen. The issue I'm having is that after the keyboard is hidden, there is still a little indicator/cursor on the EditText.

How can I hide this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the xml attribute android:cursorVisible or the java function setCursorVisible(boolean).

Comment: This was close enough to the answer I was looking for. The specific problem I had was that I wanted to be able to hide the cursor instantly but that isn't an issue any more. Many thanks for taking the time to answer!